# Bitmap memory utilization Android

Tags: android, memory

I have an application that uses a custom adapter to load images into a listview. The adapter uses a memory cache. I have noticed that over time the memory usage gradually increases in the app.

Using MAT, it indicates a problem suspect as being android.graphics.bitmap. As I use the app the instances of this class steadily grows along with the occupied bytes.

My question is: Where would be a good place to start troubleshooting this issue? I can post the code, but am not sure what is relevant at this point. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You're creating a Bitmap cache, right? Why do you find it unusual that the number of instances of Bitmap grows? That's sort of the point, right? Is it to the extent that it's causing out of memory errors? Are you ever clearing anything from the cache?

Comment: Yes using Bitmap cache. The part I find unusual is that navigating away from this list into another part of the app and the anaylyzing a heap dump still shows the bitmaps in memory. No I am not clearing anything, should I be?

Comment: Is the cache local to that particular Activity? Bitmaps don't immediately get removed on Android once references are lost -- to accelerate the process, you can call `recycle()` on each `Bitmap`, but only after you are CERTAIN you will not be trying to draw them any more.